# Artifactory and tomcat out of memory

Tags: tomcat, maven, artifactory

i am using artifactory 2.3.4.1 on tomcat 6
and sometimes when i am deploying or deleting from artifactory 
tomcat gets out of memory, any ideas why ?
and how to fix that, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to increase the amout of memory. Please check this [jira](https://issues.jfrog.org/jira/browse/RTFACT-3575) ticket.

Artifactory has been historically quite bad with memory management, but the developers have improved it a **lot** in the last few releases.

Comment: it says change the java_opts to -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -XX:NewSize=480m -XX:MaxNewSize=480m any ideas where to change it i am using linux?

Comment: You need to change that in the webserver where you're running artifactory. This *strongly* depends on your installation. Usually it enough to set that variable on the user which runs Tomcat, but again, it depends on your configuration, init scripts, linux distro, how tomcat was installed, etc.

Comment: so you mean the configuration for memory will be in the servlet container not the artifactory itself ?

Comment: Exactly! Usually, webapps use as much memory as it's available in the container. I'm assuming that you're running just artifactory in the servlet container.